# PyTorch: Target 1 is out of bounds

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch

I am new to Deep Learning and wondering how to modify my model to fix it.
It says Target 1 is out of bounds, so what parameter should I change to make it works. When the output is changed to `2`, it works. However, the goal for the model is to predict 2 classes classification. Also, when output is 2, the `training loss` becomes `nan`.

The `data` is a dataframe with shape `(15958, 4)` transformed into tensor format.

Sorry `Split_NN` is a class:

```
# SplitNN
# to protect privacy and split
class SplitNN:
    def __init__(self, models, optimizers):
        self.models = models
        self.optimizers = optimizers

        self.data = []
        self.remote_tensors = []

    def forward(self, x):
        data = []
        remote_tensors = []

        data.append(self.models[0](x))

        if data[-1].location == self.models[1].location:
            remote_tensors.append(data[-1].detach().requires_grad_())
        else:
            remote_tensors.append(
                data[-1].detach().move(self.models[1].location).requires_grad_()
            )

        i = 1
        while i < (len(models) - 1):
            data.append(self.models[i](remote_tensors[-1]))

            if data[-1].location == self.models[i + 1].location:
                remote_tensors.append(data[-1].detach().requires_grad_())
            else:
                remote_tensors.append(
                    data[-1].detach().move(self.models[i + 1].location).requires_grad_()
                )

            i += 1

        data.append(self.models[i](remote_tensors[-1]))

        self.data = data
        self.remote_tensors = remote_tensors

        return data[-1]
        
    def backward(self):
        for i in range(len(models) - 2, -1, -1):
            if self.remote_tensors[i].location == self.data[i].location:
                grads = self.remote_tensors[i].grad.copy()
            else:
                grads = self.remote_tensors[i].grad.copy().move(self.data[i].location)
    
            self.data[i].backward(grads)

    def zero_grads(self):
        for opt in self.optimizers:
            opt.zero_grad()

    def step(self):
        for opt in self.optimizers:
            opt.step()
```

Below are the codes:

Model set up: The Model is a sequential deep learning model, which I tried to use `nn.linear` to generated binary prediction.

```
torch.manual_seed(0)

# Define our model segments

input_size = 3
hidden_sizes = [128, 640]
output_size = 1


# original models
models = [
    nn.Sequential(
        nn.Linear(input_size, hidden_sizes[0]),
        nn.ReLU(),
        nn.Linear(hidden_sizes[0], hidden_sizes[1]),
        nn.ReLU(),
    ),
    nn.Sequential(nn.Linear(hidden_sizes[1], output_size), nn.LogSoftmax(dim=1)),
]


# Create optimisers for each segment and link to them

optimizers = [
    optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=0.03,)
    for model in models
]
```

Train model is here:

```
def train(x, target, splitNN):
    
    #1) Zero our grads
    splitNN.zero_grads()
    
    #2) Make a prediction
    pred = splitNN.forward(x)
    
    #3) Figure out how much we missed by
    criterion = nn.NLLLoss()
    loss = criterion(pred, target)
    
    #4) Backprop the loss on the end layer
    loss.backward()
    
    #5) Feed Gradients backward through the nework
    splitNN.backward()
    
    #6) Change the weights
    splitNN.step()
    
    return loss, pred
```

Finally the training part, also the part where problem happen:
the `send` function is for assigning model to the nodes, cuz this is set up to simulating federated learning.

```
for i in range(epochs):
    running_loss = 0
    correct_preds = 0
    total_preds = 0

    for (data, ids1), (labels, ids2) in dataloader:
        # Train a model
        data = data.send(models[0].location)
        data = data.view(data.shape[0], -1)
        labels = labels.send(models[-1].location)

        # Call model
        loss, preds = train(data.float(), labels, splitNN)

        # Collect statistics
        running_loss += loss.get()
        correct_preds += preds.max(1)[1].eq(labels).sum().get().item()
        total_preds += preds.get().size(0)

    print(f"Epoch {i} - Training loss: {running_loss/len(dataloader):.3f} - Accuracy: {100*correct_preds/total_preds:.3f}")
```

The error show the problem occurs at `loss, preds = train(data.float(), labels, splitNN)`

The actual error message:

```
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/nn/functional.py in nll_loss(input, target, weight, size_average, ignore_index, reduce, reduction)
   1836                          .format(input.size(0), target.size(0)))
   1837     if dim == 2:
-> 1838         ret = torch._C._nn.nll_loss(input, target, weight, _Reduction.get_enum(reduction), ignore_index)
   1839     elif dim == 4:
   1840         ret = torch._C._nn.nll_loss2d(input, target, weight, _Reduction.get_enum(reduction), ignore_index)

IndexError: Target 1 is out of bounds.
```

Please help me. Thank you

Comment: Hello, welcome to stackoverflow ! Please read this : https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example . In your code snippet, a lot of stuff is not defined : `model`, `data` (type, shape, that strange "send" function ...), `splitNN` and the most important, the `train` function itself. Also add the actual error message. Without these information, figuring the problem out is really hard. Cheers :)

Comment: @trialNerror Sorry for causing inconvenience. I just updated the information. Thank you for reminding ;)

Comment: No inconvenience ! Your code still does not make a lot of sense to me though. SplitNN is still not defined, and it is definitely not a function : you are calling `zero_grad`, `step`, `forward` and `backward`. The first 2 methods are usually associated with optimizers, the last is called on losses, and only forward actually belongs to a model. You need to explain this behavior. Moreover  `models` are not used, except for their locations. This is not a complete/reproducible example.

Comment: Hi @trialNerror, `SplitNN` code is updated. Thank you so much. About `models` are not used, the setting is that we sending the model to `location` and `location` do the training. The purpose of this set up is to simulate federated learning instead of centralized